# Как сделать, чтоб при скролле мышью экран не переходил на следующий для плагина fullpage?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, экран, fullpage

1. У первого экрана есть внутренний скролл.
2. У следующего экрана внутреннего скролла нет.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб при первом скролле мышью экран не переходил на следующий, а оставался в пределах первого экрана, то есть проскроллился внутри до упора, но не перешел на второй экран. А после второго скролла мышью первый экран перелистнулся на второй экран?

Плагин использую fullpage.

Answer (score 0):

normalScrollElements: '.block_normal_scroll' - при инициализации плагина указывать настройку. Где .block_normal_scroll - это класс блока, который можно нормально скролить или можно ид указат: 
normalScrollElements: '#block_normal_scroll' Где точка перед именем указывается классам, а решетка(#), ИДам.